# Can one clear a variable in a recursive function?

Tags: c++, variables, recursion

I'm trying to build a program in which it takes your name and surname as input (so far) and passes it on to upcoming functions. Now I'm trying to do something with resetting the variable in a recursive function because I thought of the following scenario: if someone somehow messes up writing their name/surname I want to give them a chance to write it again... but the program doesn't delete the "bad" data and keeps it no matter how many times the user messes up writing their name. This is the code so far:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

string name_data()
{
    string name;
    string surname;

    cout<<"Welcome to CV/resume creator. Please enter your surname: "<<endl;
    cin>>surname;

    cout<<endl<<"Now please enter your name: "<<endl;
    cin>>name;

    bool false_characters=false;
    string unallowed="!@#$%^&*()1234567890";

    for(int i=0; i<unallowed.size(); i++){
        for(int j=0; j<surname.size(); j++){
            if(unallowed[i]==surname[j]){
                cout<<"Sorry, your surname cannot possibly contain those characters in it (unless you're Elon Musk's heir).\nReturning to beginning..."<<endl;
                false_characters=true;
                name_data();
            }
        }
        for(int k=0; k<name.size(); k++){
            if(unallowed[i]==name[k]){
                cout<<"Sorry, your name cannot possibly contain those characters in it (unless you're Elon Musk's heir).\nReturning to beginning..."<<endl;
                false_characters=true;
                name_data();
            }
        }
    }

    string confirmation;
    if(false_characters!=true){
        cout<<endl<<"Your name is "+surname+" "+name+". Is that correct?"<<endl;
        cin>>confirmation;
        if(confirmation=="no"){
            cout<<"Back to beginning..."<<endl<<endl;
            surname.clear();
            name.clear();
            name_data();
        }
    }
    string full_name=surname+" "+name;
    return full_name;
}

int main()
{
    cout<<name_data();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why is this implemented recursively? Usual/simpler would be to do it iteratively, until a valid name is input. Anyway, please show sample input, desired output, and current output. It's not clear what "the program doesn't delete the "bad" data and keeps it" means. But probably you see that it ends up recursing back out again and doing weird things, which is what you told it to do... Each frame of the recursion has its own copy of every local variable, would be my hint. My next hint would be to use your debugger to see where/why exactly things go wrong.

Comment: @underscore_d The sample initial input, for example, would be Mika as surname, Patterblon as name and, since it is an undesired input (by the user), when the user is asked "Your name is Mika Patterblon. Is that correct?" he would write, as argument, "no", because he wanted to write Mike Patterson. And the program, instead of deleting Mika Patterblon and taking new input at the next operation, it keeps the first iteration, "Mika Patterblon" and shows it in main...

Comment: "it keeps the first iteration" - but you're not doing iterations. You are recursing. So when you clear the local `name`, you only clear it in the current frame of the recursion. Then eventually, you go back up a frame, and that outer frame still has whatever `name` it originally had. You can fix this by coding this normally, i.e. iteratively, not recursively.

Comment: @underscore_d you mean writing something like a "while" function until the input is correct/desired. Right?

Comment: Yes. Probably `do`/`while` in this case makes most sense.

Comment: Alright, I'll do it like this and keep you updated. Thanks a lot <3

Comment: You could probably get somewhere with the current design by doing `return name_data()` when you recurse - because right now you never do anything with the final, inner, correct result... but again, recursion doesn't make a lot of sense here.

Comment: You're certainly right. Like I said, I'm a beginner with this stuff and I was trying to see if what I do works

Comment: Beware, using recursion for input is really an *anti-pattern*. It is possible to make it work more or less by using static variables which will keep their values across different calls, yet it is a terrible design. Recursion is a great tool but must not be abused.

Comment: Is the input supposed to be restricted to letters? If so, `std::isalpha` is much simpler and faster than hand-wiring your own loop over a necessarily incomplete list of invalid characters. Especially if you combine it with [std::all_of](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of), which will save you writing that loop.

Comment: @PeteBecker thank you, Pete Becker. I'm sorry I saw the comment just now. I really looked up if it was already a function that can do that, but didn't find it until you've told me :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you need to correct the data, you call `name_data();`, hence it executes and then comes back to the scope where the data is bad. Instead, you need to make the scope where the data is bad return the data in the new scope, so do as follows. make it return not only call

```
if(confirmation=="no"){
   cout<<"Back to beginning..."<<endl<<endl;
   return name_data();
}
```

Note that you have independent data in each call stack you make, hence you don't need `clear()`.

It's better to change the recursion style to something like

```
bool repeatCond = true;

while(repeatCond){
    //your body
    //ask the user if this is satisfying and change the condition

}
```

to avoid the cost of the data and the cost of recurrsion.

Answer (score 2):

You have declared `name` and `surname` local variables in your function. When you call the function again, another copy of these variables is created. To use values collected in a recursive call, you’d have to return them and store them in the calling code but your recursive call statements

```
name_data();
```

drop the returned value. You could:

- either keep the data returned from the recursive calls and use them instead of the original ones (e.g. `return name_data();`),
- or rewrite your function to use a cycle instead of recursion.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you guys a lot for your solutions. I corrected it now with your hints and advices and it is working as I wanted. Here is the modified code for who is interested:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

string name_data()
{
    string name;
    string surname;

    cout<<"Welcome to CV/resume creator. Please enter your surname: "<<endl;
    cin>>surname;

    cout<<endl<<"Now please enter your name: "<<endl;
    cin>>name;

    bool false_characters=false;
    string unallowed="!@#$%^&*()1234567890";

    for(int i=0; i<unallowed.size(); i++){
        for(int j=0; j<surname.size(); j++){
            if(unallowed[i]==surname[j]){
                cout<<"Sorry, your surname cannot possibly contain those characters in it (unless you're Elon Musk's heir).\nReturning to beginning..."<<endl;
                false_characters=true;
                return name_data();
            }
        }
        for(int k=0; k<name.size(); k++){
            if(unallowed[i]==name[k]){
                cout<<"Sorry, your name cannot possibly contain those characters in it (unless you're Elon Musk's heir).\nReturning to beginning..."<<endl;
                false_characters=true;
                return name_data();
            }
        }
    }

    string confirmation;
    if(false_characters!=true){
        cout<<endl<<"Your name is "+surname+" "+name+". Is that correct?"<<endl;
        cin>>confirmation;
        if(confirmation=="no"){
            cout<<"Back to beginning..."<<endl<<endl;
            return name_data();
        }
    }
    string full_name=surname+" "+name;
    return full_name;
}

int main()
{
    cout<<name_data();
    return 0;
}
```